# representing to someone

Tags: meaning-in-context

I don't understand this passage from a Sherlock Holmes story (the second stain).

> It was only upon my **representing** to him that I had given a promise
>   that “The  Adventure of the Second Stain” should be published when the
>   times were  ripe,...

What does Watson mean by "representing to him"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> To render perceptible, make plain or manifest; to communicate to the senses, esp. the sight.

(OED, *represent* 8(a) )

In this case, Watson is more *reminding* Holmes of the promise, but the word usually means 'point out'.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it means the same thing as the verb 'present,' or in this case 'to inform.' See the [Online Etymological Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=represent&searchmode=none) which says:

> from L. repraesentare, from re-, intensive prefix, + praesentare "to present," lit. "to place before"